# django annotate - issue with counting nested items in the template

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

I have a list of checkboxes and labels for business challanges. I'd like to apply categories for each business challange but I am struggling to count number of business challange in each category.

This is what I have:

models.py

```
class BusinessChallangeCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        
class BusinessChallange(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessChallangeCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_business_challange')

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    business_challange = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessChallange, related_name='business_challange_product')
```

views.py

```
class ManualSearch(ListView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ManualSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        business_challange = BusinessChallangeCategory.objects.annotate(business_challange_count=Count('category_business_challange__business_challange_product'))

        context['business_challange'] = business_challange
        return context
```

test.html

```
<div class="filter-container" id="business-challange-list">
    <strong class="f-12">Business challanges</strong><br>
    {% for bc_category in business_challange %}
    <div class="fw-bold f-12">{{bc_category.title}}</div>
        {% for bc in bc_category.category_business_challange.all %}
        <div class="form-check d-flex business-challange-item">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{bc.title}}" id="{{bc.title}}" data-filter="business_challange">
            <label class="form-check-label ps-2" for="{{bc.title}}">
                {{bc.title}}
            </label>
            <span class="ms-auto ps-2 text-muted f-12">{{bc.business_challange_count}}</span> #count is not working, it doesn't appear at all
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong and how to calculate properly each business challange in each category will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are annotating the value in one queryset in template `business_challange` but then trying to access it while iterating another queryset `bc_category.category_business_challange.all`, which calls DB each time it runs. You don't need the annotation though you can call directly `{{bc.business_challange_product.count}}`. This will each issue another query though.

From performance perspective I would recommend annotating the count on the second queryset of `BusinessChallange` directly in view, instead of the `BusinessChallangeCategory` and group by category in python, so you have what you neeed in one query and one forloop iteration.